# Why does Pandas export incomplete real-time data to CSV file when converted to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm working with a dynamic system whose velocity data is stored in a matrix as such:

`Vd = [v_min, v_max, yaw_rate_min, yaw_rate_max]`

and the output is as follows when printed:

`-0.02        0.02       -1.83728716  1.83728716`

 `0.02        0.06       -0.36745743  3.30711689`

 `0.04        0.08       -1.1023723   2.57220202`

 `0.06        0.1        -1.46982973  2.20474459`

`...`

I want to export this data (specifically, maximum and minimum velocity data) to a CSV file. However, I'm unable to extract the full data as I'm only able to output a CSV file with only one row of the velocity matrix.

I have tried converting the matrix to an array, and then converting the array to a dataframe. With Pandas' `df.to_csv` syntax, I expected the full velocity matrix to be exported to a CSV file, but as mentioned before, I can only obtain one row of data. Below is the code I have written. If it makes a difference, the data is collected in real-time as the code runs. Any advice is appreciated.

`

```
Vs = [config.min_speed+config.U1, config.max_speed+config.U1,
      -config.max_yaw_rate, config.max_yaw_rate]

Vd = [x[3] - config.max_accel * config.dt,
      x[3] + config.max_accel * config.dt,
      x[4] - config.max_delta_yaw_rate * config.dt,
      x[4] + config.max_delta_yaw_rate * config.dt]

#  [v_min, v_max, yaw_rate_min, yaw_rate_max]
dw = [max(Vs[0], Vd[0]), min(Vs[1], Vd[1]),
      max(Vs[2], Vd[2]), min(Vs[3], Vd[3])] **# n x 4 matrix**
dw_arr = np.array(dw)
vMin = dw_arr[:,0] #Minimum velocity data column
vMax = dw_arr[:,1] #Maximum velocity data column
print(dw_arr)

df = pd.DataFrame([vMin, vMax])
df.to_csv('Velocity Data.csv') **# This only saves one row of data from dw_arr array**
```

`

Comment: "This only saves one row of data from dw_arr array" Well, did you try to check that `df` contains what you expect it to contain? Does it? How about `vMin` and `vMax`? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre], and identify a concrete, specific problem before asking - exactly what goes wrong, where? What exactly do you think should happen at that step instead, and **why**? Then, make sure (by **trying it yourself**) that someone else could **copy and paste** your code, **without adding anything**, and **directly** see the **exact** problem.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.